# Providing a default text for the html dropdownlistfor box which gives users a guide

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This seems simple but am not getting it. I have the GetBranch
method below which i am using to populate the dropdownlist box.
Right now it taking the first row which i dont want.
I want the first item to be "Select a branch"

Where do I put that please?

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BranchModel, new SelectList(Model.BranchModel, "Id", "BranchName"), new { @id = "ddlBranch", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })


        public List<Branch> GetBranch()
            {
                List<Branch> filterBranch;

                    filterBranch = (from c in objCustomerData
                        select new Branch()
                        {
                            Id = c.Branch,
                            BranchName = c.Branch

                        }).ToList();

                    var myResult = filterBranch.GroupBy(test => test.BranchName)
                        .Select(grp => grp.First())
                        .ToList();            

                return myResult;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this signature (from mvc dll 5.2.3)

```
DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

apply to your example

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BranchModel, new SelectList(Model.BranchModel, "Id", "BranchName"),"Select a branch" ,new { @id = "ddlBranch", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no clue on how to write this. I am new to mvc.